# Block everyone unless they give a post code

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, block

I want to setup a test on my Wordpress website. Basically what I want to do is block everyone that hasn't come from Google with a page that requires them to add their post code. Once they fill in their postcode I will redirect to the site. Then once they have got through the postcode page, a cookie will remember them and they will not see the block page again. Can this be done with htaccess or do I need to hardcode it mysellf?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Steve

Comment: I believe you just want to make sure the user have the postcode code, just validate the $_GET or $_POST parameter for the postcode code supplied, and perform your next action.

Comment: Are you / your customer aware that many visitors to sites that prompt for a postcode just find those popups extremely annoying and often just put in fake information?

Comment: Yes I do realise that Andrew. But what I am trying to do is find out who is interested enough to put in a postcode and who isn't. A bot or browser will not leave a postcode, but someone interested may leave a postcode. At the moment I am getting 200 to 300 uniques a day, but none of them are turning into enquiries. I think that the majority are bots and browsers.